# How can I separate the navigation of an XpsDocument in a DocumentViewer control from the containing NavigationWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In some WPF XAML, I'm using a [`DocumentViewer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.documentviewer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control within my [`NavigationWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow(v=vs.110).aspx) to display an XPS document (via the [`XpsDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.xpsdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class), per the simple instructions [here on the MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adrianford/archive/2007/07/14/xps-viewing-in-three-lines.aspx).

Unfortunately, the navigation within the XPS document (internal hyperlinks) propagate to the journal of the `NavigationWindow`, rather than being contained within the `DocumentViewer` control. I'm wondering how I can separate the two, perhaps using a [`Frame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that points to some XAML that contains the `DocumentViewer`, per the topic pictured [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Frame_in_Standalone_Applications). But I'm really new to this whole idea. Does anyone have or know of any code they could point me toward?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by piecing together [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Frame_in_Standalone_Applications) and [information](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dff32e56-9080-4a0d-8296-7e99133575e8/xps-document-viewer-change-page-width-from-code-toolbar-settings?forum=wpf) from MSDN. Some code fragments below in case it helps anyone else.

Within the `UserControl` navigated to by the `NavigationWindow` I placed (among other window content) the `Frame`, as shown

```
<Frame Name="xpsFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal" />
```

and in the code behind I called

```
XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(pathToDocument, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
manualFrame.Navigate(xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence());
```

This allowed the display of the XPS document within a specified portion of the `NavigationWindow` while keeping the navigation within the XPS document (in the `Frame`) separate from the main window navigation.